# How to get index value from jquery .each() function

Tags: php, jquery

I'm having trouble fetching the index of another field from 
jquery .each() function. I want to fetch the value of the 
input with the name line_id[] :

```
$('input[name=bl_caps[]]').each(function(index){

    var line_id = $('input[name=line_id[]]').val();
    var caps = $(this).val();
    alert('line id: ' + line_id + '<br/>' + 'caps: ' + caps);

});
```

HTML:

```
<?php foreach(){ ?>
<input type="hidden" name="line_id[]" id="line_id" value="<?php echo $sbl->BusLineID; ?>"/>
<td><input type="text" name="bl_caps[]" id="bl_caps"/></td>
<?php } ?>
```

I'm planning to do it like this:

```
var line_id = new Array();

                        $('input[name=line_id[]]').each(function(index){
                            line_id[index] = $(this).val();
                        });


                        $('input[name=bl_caps[]]').each(function(index){

                            var line_ids = line_id[index];
                            var caps = $(this).val();
                            alert('line id: ' + line_ids + '<br/>' + 'caps: ' + caps);

                        });
```

But I'm hoping that I could find a better answer here:)

Comment: I'm a little confused as to what you want. What you have looks perfectly fine to me if you want the index (0,1,2,3...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to to do what you're trying to do is to use the [.prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) function:

```
$('input[name=bl_caps[]]').each(function(){
    // get the previous sibling
    var line_ids = $(this).prev().val();
    var caps = $(this).val();
    alert('line id: ' + line_ids + '<br/>' + 'caps: ' + caps);
});
```

Note that this only works if you put the hidden input *inside* the `td` element, which is where it should be anyway:

```
<?php foreach(){ ?>
<td>
    <input type="hidden" name="line_id[]" id="line_id" value="<?php echo $sbl->BusLineID; ?>"/>
    <input type="text" name="bl_caps[]" id="bl_caps"/>
</td>
<?php } ?>
```

For mapping values to an array, you might try the [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) function:

```
var line_ids = $('input[name=line_id[]]').map(function(){
    return $(this).val();
}).toArray();
```

Note that it gives you a jQuery object, not a true array, hence the `.toArray()` call at the end.